zlib inflate() partly hangs while uncompressing buffer
I use zlib 1.3.1 on MicroChip/XC32. It's imported through included Harmony and it translates perfect. My goal is to receive data via a serial connection through various ways. This already works with uncompressed data. To save time i want to compress the data and i made tests with an amount of 4k, 8k and now 16k blocks of uncompressed binary data. I transfer the data within a loop and inflate() it on the microcontroller.
For transfering the datablocks i use Python3.6 importing zlib( 1.2.10 ) there.
The code is:
  # create compressor with user defined options
  compressor = zlib.compressobj( level=zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION, wbits=zlib.MAX_WBITS )
  
  data = compressor.compress(datablock) + compressor.flush() # datablock size is 16k

  send the data ...


The microcontroller code after receiving the data in in rcvbuf[] is:
#include "zlib.h"

uint8_t             rcv_buf[LEN_RCV_BUF];              // LEN_RCV_BUF = 17000
//uint8_t             decompress_buf[LEN_RCV_BUF];
uint8_t             decompress_buf[40000];             // increased for testing
uint8_t             my_adr[40000];                     // increased for testing




/*
*
* rcv_buf is already filled, when this function is called
*
*
*/
void cmd_write_to_myadr(void) {


volatile z_stream   out_stream;   // zlib struct
uint16_t            have;
int                 ret;    
uint16_t            dat_len = ( rcv_buf[5] << 8 ) + rcv_buf[6];



/* allocate inflate state */
out_stream.zalloc     = Z_NULL;
out_stream.zfree      = Z_NULL;
out_stream.opaque     = Z_NULL;
out_stream.avail_in   = 0;
out_stream.next_in    = Z_NULL;

ret = inflateInit( &out_stream ); // HEAP-Size

if( ret != Z_OK ) {
  
//                      return ret;                 
  
  // neg_response(); // AAA
  return; 
}


// rcv_buf[7];     =>    != 0 means data is compressed !

out_stream.avail_in    =  dat_len;
out_stream.next_in     = &rcv_buf[8];
out_stream.avail_out   =  sizeof( decompress_buf );
out_stream.next_out    = &decompress_buf[0];


// run DE-compression 
ret = inflate( &out_stream,  Z_NO_FLUSH );

assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);  /* state not clobbered */

switch( ret ) {
  
  case Z_NEED_DICT  :
    ret = Z_DATA_ERROR;     /* and fall through */
  case Z_DATA_ERROR :
  case Z_MEM_ERROR  :
    inflateEnd( &out_stream );
//                            return ret;
//              negativ_response();
  return;                             // BreakPoint is here !!!
  case Z_STREAM_END :
    break;
  default:
    return;                           // BreakPoint is here !!!
}

have = sizeof( decompress_buf ) - out_stream.avail_out;
memWrite_sram_buffer( my_adr, &decompress_buf[0], have );
my_adr += have;


inflateEnd( &out_stream );

}


I'm transfering binary data(images and code).
The things is, depending on the content of the compressed datablocks it works or not.
I tried different options and window sizes but i run always into the same problem after different calls to inflate().
Setting up a breakpoint after the inflate() function indicates to me it hangs inside there.
Using Python3 is only for testing at the moment and will be replaced later on with C++ Code.
Is it because of using two different versions of zlib for compress(deflate) and inflate?

What exactly happens when "it works or not"? How do you tell? What is the return code from inflate()? What do you mean "hangs"? How does something "partly hang"?? You need to be much, much more specific about what you are seeing, and how. Also provide all of your code. How is decompress_buf defined? What is its size? Make sure that you code is indented properly in the question.

Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH is not a valid flush value for inflate(). You should use Z_NO_FLUSH. Z_FINISH will work as well in this case, assuming that you have provided the entire compressed stream. Though it won't do anything different.

Assuming that you are providing the entire compressed stream, and you are providing enough output space for all of the decompressed data, then you do not need to loop. Just call inflate() once. As it is, your loop makes no sense, since you are not changing the available input or output for a subsequent inflate() call. The first call already did everything it could.

1:
I slice a binary file in 16k(16384) chunks and send it piecewise compressed.
"It works or not" means it works for example for the first 15 slices but at the
16th slice it seems to stay within inflate().
I don't receive a return code and dont run into the two breakpoints.
Sorry, "hangs" is a german saying when it runs into a loop and doesn't
find out anymore (it hung up, it has taken the rope).

2:
I use "Z_NO_FLUSH" now.

3:
I have eliminated the loop now.
I increased the HEAP-buffer from 512 Bytes to 40000 Bytes because i saw you
use calloc() and i found a comment inflate() needs about 32kByte + 7 kByte.

Again, you need to provide all of your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Provide code in its entirety that can be compiled. inflate can't hang, unless perhaps you are somehow overwriting its working storage.

Sorry i'm new, i have updated the code above

Still not complete.

I don't see zlib.h included.

I 've updated again the code section. This is all regarding zlib. Compiling is not not the problem. As the library is well proofed i assumed i i'm using a wrong parameter.

You're not getting it. It doesn't matter if compiling is not the problem. If we can't compile it, we can't help you.

The OP seems rather reluctant to provide complete code that can be compiled in the question, nor any test code to run it, nor any test case data, but after some work on their latest update, I got this to compile (see %% comments for what was changed):
#include <assert.h>                             // %% added for assert()
#include "zlib.h"

#define LEN_RCV_BUF 17000                       // %% added

uint8_t             rcv_buf[LEN_RCV_BUF];              // LEN_RCV_BUF = 17000
//uint8_t             decompress_buf[LEN_RCV_BUF];
uint8_t             decompress_buf[40000];             // increased for testing
uint8_t             my_adr[40000];                     // increased for testing

/*
 *
 * rcv_buf is already filled, when this function is called
 *
 */
unsigned cmd_write_to_myadr(void) {             // %% added returned length

    z_stream   out_stream;   // zlib struct  %% removed "volatile"
    uint16_t            have;
    int                 ret;
    uint16_t            dat_len = ( rcv_buf[5] << 8 ) + rcv_buf[6];

    /* allocate inflate state */
    out_stream.zalloc     = Z_NULL;
    out_stream.zfree      = Z_NULL;
    out_stream.opaque     = Z_NULL;
    out_stream.avail_in   = 0;
    out_stream.next_in    = Z_NULL;

    ret = inflateInit( &out_stream ); // HEAP-Size

    if( ret != Z_OK ) {
        //                      return ret;

        // neg_response(); // AAA
        return 0;
    }

    // rcv_buf[7];     =>    != 0 means data is compressed !

    out_stream.avail_in    =  dat_len;
    out_stream.next_in     = &rcv_buf[8];
    out_stream.avail_out   =  sizeof( decompress_buf );
    out_stream.next_out    = &decompress_buf[0];

    // run DE-compression
    ret = inflate( &out_stream,  Z_NO_FLUSH );

    assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);              /* state not clobbered */

    switch( ret ) {

    case Z_NEED_DICT  :
        ret = Z_DATA_ERROR;                     /* and fall through */
    case Z_DATA_ERROR :
    case Z_MEM_ERROR  :
        inflateEnd( &out_stream );
        //                            return ret;
        //              negativ_response();
        return 0;                               // BreakPoint is here !!!
    case Z_STREAM_END :
        break;
    default:
        return 0;                               // BreakPoint is here !!!
    }

    have = sizeof( decompress_buf ) - out_stream.avail_out;

    // %% commenting out undefined function and illegal arithmetic on constant
    // %% pointer
    // %% memWrite_sram_buffer( my_adr, &decompress_buf[0], have );
    // %% my_adr += have;

    inflateEnd( &out_stream );
    return have;                                // %% added
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t got = fread(rcv_buf + 8, 1, sizeof(rcv_buf) - 8, stdin);
    rcv_buf[5] = got >> 8;
    rcv_buf[6] = got;
    unsigned have = cmd_write_to_myadr();
    fwrite(decompress_buf, 1, have, stdout);
    return 0;
}

I ran this with zlib-compressed data, and it decompressed correctly. No substantive changes were made to the original code, so the problem is somewhere else. Perhaps in the data generation, including the header with two bytes of length, in the placement of the compressed data (again, the OP provided incomplete Python code for the generation of test data), or the transmission and reception of the data.

Is it because of using two different versions of zlib for
compress(deflate) and inflate?

No. All versions of zlib's compressed data and decompression of that data are fully compatible both forward and backwards, for the past nearly 30 years.

Hello Mark,
Sorry for the delay, but I live in Europe and we have a time difference of about 8 to 9 hours.
It was very late yesterday and i just needed a nudge in the right direction.
I know who you are and I really appreciate your work. I also didn't expect you to answer me yourself.

In this case it's a little  bit difficult to provide test code as i'm working on a microcontroller that receives its input data serially.
The memory function memWrite_sram_buffer() is also not real. It writes data via an SPI interface to the RAM of an external chip that displays some graphics.

But you already helped me a lot. Using ZLIB is new for me and it's much easier for me now to know that i have to call inflate() only one time in this case.
I already transmitted about 10 different pictures with about 60k uncompressed and i had no problems.
Problems started using a bigger file (10MByte) with a different content or using smaller slices(8k). The compression ratio of the sliced data is fantastic.

My guess is also towards the header of the data generated by Python. I will move to another tool which i will write program in "C".
Thanks a lot  for your answers.
